# JTextArea issue when writing. No limit texts go down the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

There is a problem with my `JTextArea`. When I write, it goes down the frame and I don't know how to limit it so no more lines below the `JFrame`

Photo:
[image: describing my problem]

Comment: You can try wrapping the JTextArea in a JScrollPane

Comment: but I have to add a scroll bar right?

Comment: JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); pane.add(textArea);

Comment: @LazyCubicleMonkey, that code will NOT work. You don't add a component to the scrollpane. You add the component to the viewport of the scrollpane. Or the easy way is to specify the component when you create the scrollpane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I have found a solution!  I've discovered that making a JTextArea scrollable is **based on the design** of the program.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468550/getting-jtextpane-to-scroll) is what helped me to get my JTextPane to work and is what I will be using as a reference.  This is not the only way to do this, but if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask!  Thanks.

---

As stated by others, you need to wrap your JTextArea in JScrollPane

```
public class ScrollableJTextArea
{
    JTextArea jTextArea     = new JTextArea();

    // Wrap JTextArea in a JScrollPane
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);
    ...
```

---

Define a constructor for your GUI

```
ScrollableJTextArea()
{
    jTextArea.setLineWrap(true); // wrap text horizontally
    jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380,350));
    // and so on...
}
```

---

And your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ScrollableJTextArea sjta = new ScrollableJTextArea();
    JFrame frame             = new JFrame();
    JPanel center            = new JPanel();

    // I've read on many forums as well as heard from many fellow classmates 
    // that it's better to add content to a panel rather than the frame itself
    frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    center.add(sjta.jScrollPane);

    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

Comment: wow awesome! let me check it tomorrow after I'm done with my Software Engineering final. Much appreciation for your time solving this.

Comment: @iMohammad How did your final go?  Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to place the `JTextArea` instance in a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). This will make the content of the text area scrollable.

Comment: Is it possible for me just to wrap it? Because I don't want to use Scrollbar.

Comment: @iMohammad, And why don't you want to use the scrollbar?

Comment: @iMohammad, your comment makes no sense. You need the scrollbar so the user can scroll to see the rest of the text. Just like you need to the scrollbar on this posting to see all the answers. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for the basics BEFORE you post a question. And next time post your SSCCE, not a picture.

Answer (score 0):

compare `getRows()` and `getLineCount()` whenever the body gains another "line" and if `getLineCount()` is greater than `getRows()` then trim using `getText()` and `setText()`

Answer (score 0):

You can us `JScrollPane` to do so.

```
private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(12, 30);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);  // create ScrollPane and add textArea in it
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // or whatever layout you are using
```

But it makes no sense why you want to do so. But if in case you dont want to use `JScrollPane` you can use the following code to force the `JTextArea` to go to the end of `JTextArea`.

```
textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
```

Hope this helps.